# Runtime exception is @ApplicationException(rollback=false) but transaction is finally rolled back

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

My runtime exception

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=false)
public class UncheckedException extends RuntimeException {}
```

My EJB code

```
@Stateless
@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ContainerManagedTransactionBean {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public void insertAndThrowUnchecked() throws UncheckedException {
        em.persist(new Entry());
        throw new UncheckedException();
    }

}
```

My another EJB is client

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Transactional(TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class Start {

    @EJB
    ContainerManagedTransactionBean bean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        //...       
        try {
            bean.insertAndThrowUnchecked();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Start unchecked exception catched");
        }
    }
```

Could someone explain me why  `insertAndThrowUnchecked` is rolled back?

In similar case, when exception is checked,

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=false)
public class CheckedException extends Exception {}
```

transaction is committed.

Working example is at [this GitHub link](https://github.com/michaldo/ejb-transactions).

I will appreciate clear explanation and link to proper part of EJB specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per section 7.1 of the EJB 3.2 specification:

> It is illegal to associate JTA transactional interceptors (see [8])
>   with Enterprise JavaBeans. The EJB Container should fail deployment of
>   such applications.[39]
>
> [39] This restriction may be removed in a future release of this specification.

Since the `@Transactional` annotation is incorrectly being used to specify a JTA transaction interceptor on an EJB , the `@ApplicationException` annotation has no effect.  Try using the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation instead.